# Can I push array object to empty array on mongodb? (using go)

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I'm trying to learn mongodb by using go.
I tried to push array to mongodb's empty array.

First, I created a collection like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c6c2d7b64d7f9d461d2bd5"),
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "description" : "This is test vote title",
    "candidates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test Name",
            "score" : 0,
            "voter" : []
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are the types that I used for db

```
type Vote struct {
    Title       string
    Description string
    Candidates  []Candidate
}

type Candidate struct {
    Name  string
    Score int
    Voter []Supporter
}

type Supporter struct {
    UUID string
    Name string
}
```

And, What I want to do is, push array object to empty array 'voter'.
I want to push this object to db.

```
[]vote.Supporter{{UUID: uuid.NewString(), Name: "Test User A"}, {UUID: uuid.NewString(), Name: "Test User B"}}
```

Then, I pushed this array object uses this command.

```
vote.VoteToSubject(collection, "Test Title", "Test Name", []vote.Supporter{{UUID: uuid.NewString(), Name: "Test User A"}, {UUID: uuid.NewString(), Name: "Test User B"}})
```

```
func VoteToSubject(collection *mongo.Collection, title string, name string, voter []Supporter) {
    // filter := bson.D{{"title", title}, {"candidates", bson.D{{"name", name}}}}
    filter := bson.D{{"$and", []interface{}{bson.D{{"title", title}}, bson.D{{"candidates.name", name}}}}}
    update := bson.D{{"$set", bson.D{{"candidates.votes", voter}}}}
    updateResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Matched %v documents and updated %v documents.\n", updateResult.MatchedCount, updateResult.ModifiedCount)
}
```

What I expected is that, array object is added to the votes empty array (not replace).

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c6c2d7b64d7f9d461d2bd5"),
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "description" : "This is test vote title",
    "candidates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test Name",
            "score" : 0,
            "voter" : [
                {
                    "uuid" : *uuid1*
                    "name" : *name1*
            },  {
                    "uuid" : *uuid2*
                    "name" : *name2*
            }, 
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But that command returns an error... like this.

```
ekfkal79@DARAMI-PC MINGW64 ~/go/src/github.com/ekfkal79/go-mongo-db (main)
$ go run main.go
Connected to MongoDB!
2021/06/14 11:45:52 multiple write errors: [{write errors: [{Cannot create field 'votes' in element {candidates: [ { name: "Test Name", score: 0, voter: [] } ]}}]}, {<nil>}]
exit status 1
```

I don't know how to resolve this problem... I read the mongodb's doc, but It didn't help...
I need your help...

Sorry for my poor English skill...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I solved my problem!

The problem was that, I didn't specify an index of my array!!

```
func VoteToSubject(collection *mongo.Collection, title string, name string, voter []Supporter) {
    // filter := bson.D{{"title", title}, {"candidates", bson.D{{"name", name}}}}
    filter := bson.D{{"$and", []interface{}{bson.D{{"title", title}}, bson.D{{"candidates.name", name}}}}}
    update := bson.D{{"$addToSet", bson.D{{"candidates.$.voter", bson.D{{"$each", voter}}}}}}
    updateResult, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Matched %v documents and updated %v documents.\n", updateResult.MatchedCount, updateResult.ModifiedCount)
}
```

In variable 'update', I specified index of array to '$'. Then unstructured array 'voter' by using '$each' query!

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60c6c2d7b64d7f9d461d2bd5"),
    "title" : "Test Title",
    "description" : "This is test vote title",
    "candidates" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Test Name",
            "score" : 0,
            "voter" : [ 
                {
                    "uuid" : "92b5eff2-b4de-4b48-96d8-9ea41a74c22b",
                    "name" : "Test User A"
                }, 
                {
                    "uuid" : "f50037ec-d898-4b6e-a836-7cc44e306493",
                    "name" : "Test User B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It is perfectly working!!

Thanks for everyone!